# Tensorflow Keras, using generator with a .h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, h5py

I have a .h5 file with about 2mil 256x256 images. The data doesn't fit into memory, which is why I am using a generator. I am wondering if I am iterating over the .h5 file in the correct way (currently using the h5py package).

(The reason why I am wondering is because the model is training very slowly (680ms/step). But this could also be because of other reasons.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pklac.png)

The code for the generator:

```py
class Generator:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        #self.data = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')
        self.file_path = file_path

    def __call__(self):
        with h5py.File(self.file_path, 'r') as data:
            for key in data.keys():
                obj = data[key]
                #X = np.array(obj['X'][()])
                Y = np.array(obj['Y'][()]) * normalization_factor
                Y = Y.reshape(256,256,1)
                yield (Y, Y)
```

The code for creating the tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

```py
def dataset(path_to_data, batch_size):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        Generator(path_to_data),
        output_signature = (
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.float32),
        )
    ).batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the issue slow training speed? If so, you should benchmark the generator performance separately. Is every image stored as a separate dataset (aka key)?  If so, that _could_ be a bottleneck. HDF5 I/O performance is better reading large volumes of data a few times (vs small volumes a lot of times). However, if every image is a separate dataset you are stuck. Dataset compression and chunking can also affect I/O performance. Check attributes `obj.chunks` and `obj.compression` You have to create a new H5 file to change them.